# I have two functions updating the same property. One updates in both console and on the page. The other only updates in the console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am writing a movie ticket ordering-type of app for a school project.  I have to use Vuejs.  And it has to be build such that, if my instructor changes the selections from 3 movies (my current setting) to some other number, it will still work.  So that's why the for loops.

Right now, I can display the movies, and the user can click on **Child Ticket** or **Adult Ticket** under any of the movies (pulled from tmdb, via Axios, and it will drop a `"1"` in the table that's the summary of what is ordered, in the correct spot.  This happens with the `v-on:click` on each of the buttons that calls the function `addChildTicket` or `addAdultTicket`.  I use `movie.adultOrdered = "1";` to insert the `adultOrdered` attribute into the movie array.  And that updates automatically on the page to a `1`.

But then, I want to be able to click the `+` or `-` symbols next to the `1` to adjust the count.  So far I'm only testing with the `+` by the adult ticket ordered for each movie.  It will update `adultOrdered` to `2` if I click the `+` in the console, because the `addTicket` function is called using `v-on:click` on the `+` sign.  And update to `3` if I click again, and so on.  But it won't update in the table at `{{movie.adultOrdered}}`, even though that's exactly where it correctly places the `1` using the `addAdultTicket` function.  Any ideas on this?

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        aryMovies:"",
        cart: 0,
    },
          
    mounted () {
        axios.get ('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=8b96ae5fa9bdac06a9ca7c4535f9a186&language=en-US&page=1')

        .then( (results) => {
            this.aryMovies = results.data.results
        })
    },

    methods: {
        addToCart(){
            this.cart += 1                      
        },

        addChildTicket(movie){
            movie.childOrdered = "1" ;
        },

        addAdultTicket(movie){
            movie.adultOrdered = "1";
        },

        addTicket(movie){
            movie.adultOrdered ++;
            console.log(movie.adultOrdered);
        },  
    }
})
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}
.cartBar {

  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #f00606, #970404);
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 40px;
  }

.fa-shopping-cart, .cart {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.cart{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 1%;
  width:4%;
  text-align: center;
}

.movie {

  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.movieCard {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center  ;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
  /*width: 50%;*/
  /*margin-left:25%;*/
  background-color: gray;
  color:white;

}
.movie img{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
}

.title {
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.overview {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.summaryHeading {
  color:white;
}

.table{
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.19.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" >

    <div class="cartBar">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        <div class="cart">{{cart}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="movieCard">        
     <div class="movie" v-for="movie in aryMovies.slice(0, 3)">
        <img v-bind:src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300' + 
        movie.poster_path">
        <p class="title">{{movie.title}}</p>
        <p>{{movie.size}}</p>
        <p class="overview">{{movie.overview}}</p>
        <button v-on:click="addToCart(), addChildTicket(movie)" type="button" 
          name="button" class = "childTicket">Child Ticket</button>
        <button v-on:click="addToCart(), addAdultTicket(movie)" type="button" 
          name="button" class = "adultTicket">Adult Ticket</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <table class="table">
        <h2 class="summaryHeading">Ticket Summary</h2>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Movie</th>
            <th scope="col">Adult Tickets</th>
            <th scope="col">Child Tickets</th>
            <th scope="col">Subtotal</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody v-for="movie in aryMovies.slice(0, 3)" >

            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{movie.title}}</th>
                <td>{{movie.adultOrdered}} x $6.99 <button class="fas fa-plus-circle" v-on:click="addTicket(movie)">+</button> <button class="fas fa-minus-circle">-</button></td>
                console.log(movie.adultOrdered);
                <td>{{movie.childOrdered}} x $3.99 <button class="fas fa-plus-circle">+</button> <button class="fas fa-minus-circle">-</button></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><button>Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody >
      </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please remember that you're asking real people to read your code: can you please the code up a bit? Almost none of those empty lines are necessary.

Comment: I'm so sorry.  I'm still pretty new at this!  So just remove the empty lines?

Comment: just general house keeping: remove empty lines that don't need to be there, make sure the code is indented properly, etc. Usually the easier way to do this is to just take your code, drop it in your code editor/IDE/etc and pick whatever its "format code" option is. No need to do it by hand, but always remember to clean up code when posting.

Comment: Thank you, Mike.

Answer (score 1):

When a template runs it will register dependencies against any reactive data that it touches. If that reactive data subsequently changes it will cause the template to run again, updating the DOM. Note that the whole template gets run each time, not just the portion that changed.

In your first click handler you have this:

```js
addToCart(), addChildTicket(movie)
```

The method `addToCart` changes the property `cart`, which is a reactive dependency of the template. The template won't re-run immediately, it's queued, and by the time it does run you've also updated `movie.childOrdered`.

However, `movie.childOrdered` is not reactive, so changing it won't cause the template to re-run. The only reason this works is because you're also changing `cart`, which is reactive.

When you add a new property to an object it is not reactive by default. The official documentation covers that here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

So in your case the properties `childOrdered` and `adultOrdered` are not reactive because you're adding them to the `movie` object after that object has been made reactive.

There are various ways to fix this but the simplest is to use `$set`:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set

e.g.:

```js
addChildTicket(movie) {
  this.$set(movie, 'childOrdered', 1);
},
```

You'll need to do the same thing for `adultOrdered`.

To reiterate, this only applies when you add a new property to an object that is already reactive. If the property already exists then it isn't required.

Note also that there's a difference between using `"1"` and `1` in JavaScript. The former creates a string containing the character `1` whereas the latter creates an actual number `1`. In some cases you may get away with it due to type coercion but in this case it seems you want a number not a string.

An alternative approach would be to add the properties initially, before the objects become reactive:

```
mounted () {
  axios.get (/*...*/)
    .then( (results) => {
      this.aryMovies = results.data.results.map(movie => {
        return {
           ...movie,
           childOrdered: 0,
           adultOrdered: 0
        }
      })
    })
},
```

By doing it this way the objects already contain properties called `childOrdered` and `adultOrdered` when reactivity is applied, so everything will work fine when you assign them new values later.

Comment: Hi, I agree with your first solution `this.$set(movie, 'childOrdered', 1)`. However, I disagree with the second one. The vue [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) states that `Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive`

Comment: Would this have been better still if I had been able to take the results returned by Axios and just add in the adultOrdered and childOrdered elements from the very beginning?  If so, how does that happen?  I fought with that for hours and finally gave up.

Comment: @JamesMedlock I'm not sure what you mean? Isn't that exactly what my final example shows?

Comment: @JamesMedlock, which solution did you get to work? The first or the second?

Comment: addChildicket(movie) {
  this.$set(movie, 'childOrdered', 1);
},'          from "skirtle" is what worked.  But I didn't even see the part about adding it initially until I refreshed the page.  I'm sorry.  I'm going to play with that too.  Thanks again, my friends.  I appreciate this.

Comment: @JamesMedlock I doubt the second one works. I know you don't owe it to me, but it will be great if you could test the second solution for the benefit of anyone who stumbles upon this post in the future.

Comment: @Tony I think you've misunderstood. That particular line from the documentation is referring to adding properties directly to the Vue instance, which isn't possible. For normal objects the rule is that the properties have to be present before the object becomes reactive. In this particular example the objects become reactive when the array is assigned to the `aryMovies` property and I've already added the new properties by that point. You can see that same thing in the final example of that section of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that, @skirtle.. You are right. I guess I was confused by the ` ...a property must be present in the data object ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that dynamically added properties to an object aren't reactive.
Try using `this.$set(this.aryMovies[index], "adultOrdered", value)` instead.

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/so-what-actually-is-vue-set

Comment: This approach was shared in a separate comment, and you appear to have been correct.  Thank you for taking time to help me out!